# Angular JS 1.2-RC vs 1.0.8

Tags: angularjs

When I'm using the service `$http`, I am getting an error with the RC version. For some odd reason, it works perfectly fine in 1.0.8.

```
angular.factory('test', function($http) {
    return {
        get_it: function(id, callback) {
            $http.get('/get_info/' + id);
        }
});
```

I get the correct JSON data in 1.0.8, however, in version 1.2-RC, the ajax request does not even hit the url /test, but rather the current URI and returns me an HTML dump. I tried to trace the backend. What are some changes I'm not aware of in 1.2 vs. 1.0.8 for $http?

Comment: The quoted code looks odd. Do you have a complete Plunkr or jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as $http and not $scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, looks like x-Request-With header was dropped.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1004